# Google Compute Engine Group Intance keeps changing IP address

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a google VM Instance Group setup so I can use autoscale (currently turned off until I'm ready to load test) when traffic/requests increase. I'm running a standard LAMP stack to run CraftCMS.

For some reason, the static IP address keeps changing making it unavailable to update via SSH through the console. When the IP changes, my LAMP stack is gone and I have to reinstall everything.

I tried claiming a static ip address and applying it to the VM Instance but that seems to do nothing.

How do I setup a Managed Group instance so this stops happening. If the ip address keeps changing, how can I setup the A Name DNS settings so that when you go to the actual URL it points to the correct server?

It all seems to work fine when I don't setup a Managed Group Instance but a regular VM Instance. But I want autoscaling to be on so I don't have to manually manage it.

Any help with this would make my day...

Comment: I think you misunderstoodd the purpose of managed instance group, they are not intended to be used individually, but as the backend of load balancer. In case you care about individual instances, use unmanaged instance group.